# Two sections of text with different fonts, aligned at the top

Tags: minipage, alignment

I am trying to have some text in the top-left corner and some text in the top-right corner. My current implementation is almost exactly what I want. Almost.

```
\usepackage{fontawesome5} % For faIcon

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
            {\Huge My full name, title} \\ %
            \vspace{0.1cm}
            {\color{UI_blue} \Large{Some extra text that says some things }} \\
    \end{minipage}% 
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.39\textwidth}
            \flushright   
            \large\href{mailto:myemail@gmail.com}{myemail@gmail.com 
                \hspace{0.3cm} {\color{UI_blue}\faIcon{envelope}}} \\
            \href{https://mywebsite.github.io/}{mywebsite.github.io 
                \hspace{0.3cm}{\color{UI_blue}\faIcon{link}}} \\
            +01 (2)3 45678910 
                \hspace{0.3cm}{\color{UI_blue}\faIcon{phone-square-alt}} \\
    \end{minipage}   
\end{center}
```

[image]

As can be seen, the top of the left text and the top of the right text do not align. That is, the larger font on the left is adding some white space to the smaller font on the left.

Is there a way to get both pieces of text aligned at the top, like this: (paint edit, the line just to visually emphasize the alignment I mean)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a `\vspace{0pt}` directly after the "minipage-line" then everything should work. Then, a full MWE would look like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome5} % For faIcon
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{center}
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.6\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
            {\Huge My full name, title} \\ %
            \vspace{0.1cm}
            {\color{blue} \Large{Some extra text that says some things }} \\
        \end{minipage}% 
        %
        \begin{minipage}[t]{0.39\textwidth}\vspace{0pt}
            \flushright   
            \large\href{mailto:myemail@gmail.com}{myemail@gmail.com 
                \hspace{0.3cm} {\color{blue}\faIcon{envelope}}} \\
            \href{https://mywebsite.github.io/}{mywebsite.github.io 
                \hspace{0.3cm}{\color{blue}\faIcon{link}}} \\
            +01 (2)3 45678910 
            \hspace{0.3cm}{\color{blue}\faIcon{phone-square-alt}} \\
            \vfill
        \end{minipage}   
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That did the trick! I tried `vspace` but didn't think to add it to both minipages.